# Constant Wave Function in 2D Circles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Let's say I have a circle. Inside this circle, there exists an electron of energy $E$. The potential inside this circle ($r < R$) is $V$ and outside, it's infinity.

Can the wave function be a constant? Let's say I want a uniform distribution across the surface. Due to the boundary condition of $ \int_{0}^{R} |\psi |^{2} dA=1 $, We can get a wave function of $ \psi = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi R^2}} $

1. Is this a valid wave function? If not, why? I read that for some boundary condition, the wave function cannot be constant. How do we know for which system can the wave function be a constant?
2. Is it a valid solution of the Schrodinger equations?
3. If it is a valid solution of the SE, then, this does means $V = E$ all over the surface of the circle, right?

If I'm missing any fundamental concept, please understand, I'm new to quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a circle. Inside this circle, there exists an
> electron of energy $E$. The potential inside this circle ($r < R$) is $V$
> and outside, it's infinity.

This is the equivalent for an electron in a square (or rectangular) box with zero potential inside and infinite potential outside but with a circular domain (instead of a square or rectangular one).

Because of the circularity, we use polar coordinates for the $\nabla$ operator in the (time independent) Schrödinger equation on the domain $r\in [0,R]$, so we have:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Big(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial
\theta^2}\Big)=Eu$$
We also have a boundary condition:

$$u(R)=0$$

I solved this problem several years ago [on these here pages](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=18#pid452671). It includes the full derivation and some interesting graphs (it's a little fragmented so keep scrolling)

The solution is very different from what you imagine, I'm afraid.

**Sample: squared normalised wave function $|u(r)|^2$ for $m=2$ and $n=2$:**

[image: Squared wave function]

Light coloured areas show *high probability density*, blood red areas have zero probability areas.

As regards the allowed energy levels for this system, we obtained:

$$E_{m,n}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2mR^2}z_{m,n}^2$$

Where $z_{m,n}$ are the roots of the Bessel function:

$$J_m(kR)=0$$

Comment: Thank you for the webpage, it helped me on understanding the equation more. and yes, I forgot to include that specific boundary condition, thanks for adding. However, I still don't quite understand why we could not have a constant as a wave function. If the probability dist is uniform, then it would still be independent of the radius and angle, right? I am trying to prove (or rather disprove) that a wave function in this system can be constant by working in reverse and trying to find a contradiction somewhere along the way (if this is a way to do it).

Comment: The wave function is the solution to the SE, whatever the SE is. In this case it's *reasonably* simple because there's no potential function $V(r)$ for $r<R$. But even for this simple problem $u$ (commonly $\psi$) is a fairly complicated function. You CANNOT impose a probability distribution: $|\psi(r)|^2$ FOLLOWS from the SE. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. So it's the method of proving that is not valid? Then the only way to prove such constant wave function is (not) valid is by solving it through SE?

Comment: @MichaelTeguhLaksana At a point where the potential is infinite the wave function is zero. I don't know of a proof of this but you can imagine that if you start in a region with a finite potential $V_0$ and then keep increasing it then the chance of finding the particle there goes to zero as $V_0\rightarrow\infty$. Since the wavefunction is zero at the boundaries the wavefunction can't be a constant otherwise it would be zero everywhere.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion: as $V\to +\infty$ the particle experiences an infinite 'containment' force: e.g. $F(x)=-\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}x}$